# Feature Request: More obvious notification for "comment too long"

Tags: feature-request, comments, character-limit

Please provide a more obvious way of notifying a less observant user (like myself) when their comment exceeds the allowed size.

I realize that there is a '-`n` characters left' under the comment box, but, silly me ,I just kept clicking the 'Add Comment' button and nothing happened.

How about graying out the 'Add Comment' button when the character limit is exceeded?

Or, not allowing the user to type more than the limit number of characters?

Just as an experiment I achieved -4193704 characters left before my browser started getting unhappy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that it already causes the "-`N` characters left" message to flash when you click the comment, but I think some simple style rules could call this out more, especially in conjunction with the flashing:

1. As soon as it reaches `< 0` characters left, change text to white and background-color to `#cc0000`
2. Gray out (something like `#cccccc`) the text on the "Add Comment" button to indicate that nothing will happen when clicked.
3. (As it does now) flash the "characters left" message if "Add Comment" is clicked

[image]